# Dependency Injection inside a Class Library How to?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I have class library project and most of classes are internal which are not accessible from outside. I want to inject those classes dependency from inside this library. I have no idea how can I do that?

Sample Code :

```
internal interface IClass1
{

}

internal class Class1 : IClass1
{

}

internal class Class2
{
    private readonly IClass1 _class1;
    // I want to inject this interface from inside this project.
    //Not from outside this project.
    // Because this class may not accessible from other class. 
    internal Class2(IClass1 class1) 
    {
        _class1 = class1;   
    }

    internal Class2() :this(new Class1())
    {
        // I do it this way.
        // But i want to do it using any IOC container 
    }
}
```

Comment: did you come up with a good way to solve this? I am facing the same issue and not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

There are few options I can advise:

1. It's possible to register those type in container, but you have to play with reflection, and use non-generic registration API. May be Ninject can help on the way, but I didn't find anything meaningful in the documentation.
2. If you can modify the source of a library, it's possible to create container registration library with NinjectModule, and then apply [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to the original library.

Comment: could use a module (windsor calls these installers) inside the library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with this, as I'm a newbie in using IoC (DI). But I've seen a feature in the Enterprise Library (unity) of having child containers, hierarchies of containers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660895(v=pandp.20).aspx#container_differentmappings

Can't you have a child container in your library, as public, so it can be used to inject objects from inside of your assembly? (having the parent IoC container in another assembly).

Not sure if all IoCs have this feature (I've used only Unity till now).